# Why is newline escape sequence not being converted into newline character?

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, escaping

I'm trying to send an email using codeigniter, and would like the message to span over several lines.

```
$address = $this->input->post('email');
$subject = 'Please complete your registration';
$message = 'Thanks for registering! \n To complete your registration, please click on (or copy and paste in your browser) the following link: ' . base_url(). "users/confirmRegistration/" . $confirmation_code; //note the '\n' after thanks for registering

$this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('me@mysite.com', 'myname');
    $this->email->to($address); 
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);    
    $this->email->send();
```

I would expect the mail to arrive with a line break after "Thanks for registering", but instead i get

> Thanks for registering! n To complete your registration (etc etc...)

I've tried with \r\n but the result is almost the same:

> Thanks for registering! rn To complete (etc etc). It's like there were a stripslash function applied..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PHP doesn't parse escape sequences like `\n` inside single quotes.

You need to enclose your message string in double-quotes.

Answer (score -1):

You need to type body in this format.
It works fine.
Rahul

$body = 'Dear ' . $row->fname . ' '. $row->lname . ',' . '

' . 'Your account with us has been temporarily disabled.' . '

' . 'Our facilitator relationship team shall contact you soon.' . '

' . 'You can also get in touch with us on info@ggg.com' . '

' . 'Warm Regards, ' . '

' . ' The  Team';